# How can I reuse a class between a few addons

Tags: python, add-on

I have the following situation. I have a class (let's call it GeometryCalculator) with many functions which I would like to reuse between a few addons. How can I do it in a way that the GeometryCalculator is a part of each addon. If a user has 5 addons installed and then he uninstalls any of them the rest of addons can still use this common class. Should all addons have a copy of the GeometryCalculator class in their folder? Any ideas how to do it are welcome. Are there any guidelines how this should be tackled? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside your scripts folder you have `addons` and maybe `addons_contrib` and a `modules` folder.

[image]

The modules folder can added if it's not there and used to store files that you want to access from various add-ons. In this case I have a file which stores functions, but it could store classes (anything a .py file is used for).

Imagine the modules folder has a folder inside called 'some_name',

[image]

and some_name contains a python file called functions,

[image]

so the path is `scripts/modules/some_name/functions.py` . To import that module in an addon you write

```
from some_name import functions
```

---

Potentially this makes installing your add-on a little bit more involved for the average novice user, unless you write code that places the files in the modules folder automatically

Comment: Ok Thanks for the answer Zeffii. I need to look into it and test it a bit. Just a small follow up question: In case there are a few addons using the functions.py module from module folder - which one of them should actually delete the functions.py during addon removal?

Comment: A fair question! A python file can tell you its current location on disk using `__file__`, meaning you can search relative to that for the modules folder, but the tricky issue is that Blender may use several places to store addons.  This is probably worthy of a new stand-alone question, it may be more involved than I want to answer in a comment, hope you understand (that way it can be found by other people asking the same question too)

Comment: Ok thanks Zeffii. I just want to add a small comment. I use windows and the addons are usually installed in place like: C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Roaming/Blender Foundation/Blender/2.74/scripts/addons/. So it seems that if an addon is using an import like "from some_name import functions" you can basically create a folder "some_name" inside the above path for addons and add the modules there as well. the addon should be able to load that.   However with this approach the folder "some_name" is left on the disk when uninstalling the addon...

Comment: well, it really depends how the user installs the addon, personally I stick everything into a separate scripts folder (can be set in user preferences - File - Scripts ), not in AppData or the linux/osx equivalent. So I think your best bet is to do cleanup relative to `__file__`

Comment: but you can also list all the possible places that blender will be looking for addons/addons_contrib/module and see if any of those contain your module. `bpy.utils.script_paths()`